# Parse dotted string, extracting last part

Tags: expansion, parsing

I want a macro that will separate a string like "1.2.3" into two parts: the part until the last dot (call that the *context*) and the last number.  This seems a pretty basic application of a helper macro and `\expandafter`, but I can't get it to terminate.

Here is my MWE, with some debugging macros thrown in:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\parse}[1]{%
    Parsing #1:\par%
    \let\my@context\@empty%
    \let\my@number\@empty%
    \expandafter\@parse#1.\@nil
    Context: \my@context\par
    Number: \my@number
}
\def\@parse#1.#2\@nil{%
    \if#2\@empty%
        \edef\my@number{#1}%
        \show\my@number%
    \else%
        \edef\my@context{\if\my@context\@empty\else\my@context.\fi#1}%
        \show\my@context%
        \expandafter\@parse#2\@nil%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
\parse{1.2.3}

\parse{4.5.6.7}

\parse{1.2}
\tracingmacros=0

\end{document}
```

As I compile this I get to what ought to be the terminating case but it doesn't succeed.  Here is the log file:

```
\parse #1->Parsing #1:\par \let \my@context \@empty \let \my@number \@empty \ex
pandafter \@parse #1.\@nil Context: \my@context \par Number: \my@number 
#1<-1.2.3

\@parse #1.#2\@nil ->\if #2\@empty \edef \my@number {#1}\show \my@number \else 
\edef \my@context {\if \my@context \@empty \else \my@context .\fi #1}\show \my@
context \expandafter \@parse #2\@nil \fi 
#1<-1
#2<-2.3.

\my@context ->

\@empty ->

> \my@context=macro:
->1.
\@parse ... \my@context .\fi #1}\show \my@context 
                                                  \expandafter \@parse #2\@n...
l.30 \parse{1.2.3}

? 

\@parse #1.#2\@nil ->\if #2\@empty \edef \my@number {#1}\show \my@number \else 
\edef \my@context {\if \my@context \@empty \else \my@context .\fi #1}\show \my@
context \expandafter \@parse #2\@nil \fi 
#1<-2
#2<-3.

\my@context ->1

\@empty ->

\my@context ->1
> \my@context=macro:
->1.2.
\@parse ... \my@context .\fi #1}\show \my@context 
                                                  \expandafter \@parse #2\@n...
l.30 \parse{1.2.3}

? 

\@parse #1.#2\@nil ->\if #2\@empty \edef \my@number {#1}\show \my@number \else 
\edef \my@context {\if \my@context \@empty \else \my@context .\fi #1}\show \my@
context \expandafter \@parse #2\@nil \fi 
#1<-3
#2<-

\@empty ->

\my@number ->

\my@context ->1.2

\my@context ->1.2
> \my@context=macro:
->1.2.3.
\@parse ... \my@context .\fi #1}\show \my@context 
                                                  \expandafter \@parse #2\@n...
l.30 \parse{1.2.3}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\@parse ...y@context \expandafter \@parse #2\@nil 
                                                  \fi 
l.30 \parse{1.2.3}

?
```

In the last successful expansion of `\@parse`, `#1` is "3" and `#2` is "".  It seems that `\@empty` expands to "" as well.  So why does `\if#2\empty` not succeed?

I welcome fancy `xparse` and `l3regex` solutions but would love a basic one as well.  There's something simple I'm not getting.

Comment: you probably meant ifx not if. `\if#2\empty ` expands tokens until it finds the first two non expandable tokens and then compares them. so if #2 is `aa` it would be true if `#2` is `ab` it would be false and if `#2` is `a` it depends what comes next and if `#2` is empty it depends on the next two things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your code *as-is* is the line:

```
\if#2\@empty
```

Suppose that the second parameter is empty.  When TeX substitutes in the parameter text then it inserts the second parameter in place of `#2`, so `#2` is not a macro that expands to the parameter text.  It *is* the parameter text.  Thus the stream becomes `\if\empty` and TeX tries to find the next thing to compare `\empty` with (in this case, `\edef` whence the test fails).

One way to fix this with minimal change to your code is to store the contents of `#2` in a macro and then test that macro.  As we're now testing macros, `\ifx` is the right choice.  So now you need:

```
\def\arg@two{#2}%
\ifx\arg@two\@empty
```

This will test to see if `#2` is empty or not, as you want.

In full:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\parse}[1]{%
    Parsing #1:\par%
    \let\my@context\@empty%
    \let\my@number\@empty%
    \expandafter\@parse#1.\@nil
    Context: \my@context\par
    Number: \my@number
}
\def\@parse#1.#2\@nil{%
  \def\arg@two{#2}%
    \ifx\arg@two\@empty%
        \edef\my@number{#1}%
        \show\my@number%
    \else%
        \edef\my@context{\if\my@context\@empty\else\my@context.\fi#1}%
        \show\my@context%
        \expandafter\@parse#2\@nil%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
\parse{1.2.3}

\parse{4.5.6.7}

\parse{1.2}
\tracingmacros=0

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Parsed strings]

Comment: (upvoted) Thanks.  Explaining the difference between "the parameter text" and a "macro that expands to the parameter text" helped a lot!

Comment: An emptyness test for `#2` might be the usual `\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax`

Answer (score 11):

After the wiz have spoken, a pragmatic solution :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\parse}[1]{
    Parsing #1:\par%
\StrCount{#1}{.}[\dotnum]
Context : \StrBefore[\dotnum]{#1}{.}\par
Number:  \StrBehind[\dotnum]{#1}{.}
}
\begin{document}

\parse{1.2.3}

\parse{4.5.6.7}

\parse{1.2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for expanding your comment to an answer.  Am I right that  the `\StrCount` line counts the number of dots in `#1` and stores that in `\dotnum`?  Then the `\StrBefore` line extracts the part of the string before the `\dotnum`th dot?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Spot on.

Answer (score 9):

A plain TeX solution:

```
\def\parse#1{%
\def\a{}%
\def\b{}%
\xparse#1.\relax.}

\def\xparse#1.#2.{%
\ifx\relax#2
  \def\b{#1}%
  \expandafter\parsestop
 \else
   \edef\a{\a\ifx\a\empty\else.\fi#1}%
  \expandafter\xparse
 \fi
 #2.}

\def\parsestop\relax.{%
  \immediate\write20{[a=\a] [b=\b]}}


\parse{1}

\parse{1.2.3}

\parse{4.5.6.7}

\parse{1.2}

\bye
```

which produces

```
[a=] [b=1]
[a=1.2] [b=3]
[a=4.5.6] [b=7]
[a=1] [b=2]
 )
No pages of output.
```

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\parse}{m}
 {
  \leingang_parse:n { #1 }
  Context~is~\tl_use:N \l_leingang_context_tl;~suffix~is~\tl_use:N \l_leingang_suffix_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l_leingang_context_tl
\tl_new:N \l_leingang_suffix_tl
\seq_new:N \l__leingang_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \leingang_parse:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__leingang_temp_seq { . } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__leingang_temp_seq \l_leingang_suffix_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_leingang_context_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__leingang_temp_seq { . } { . } { . }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\parse{1.2.3}

\parse{4.5.6.7}

\parse{1.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The argument is split into components at the periods; the last component is detached and put in `\l_leingang_suffix_tl` for further usage; from what remains 
the token list `\l_leingang_context_tl` is formed, reinserting the periods.

Comment: Thank you for the LaTeX3 version.  I look forward to learning the L3 syntax at some point.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Beware that there's a limitation with the current code: spaces around the periods will disappear. But it's not so difficult to maintain them, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another variant of David Carlisle's solution. In this solution, the command `\parsestop` isn't necessary and `\a` is scoped. Also, we watch out for null/empty tokens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\parse#1{\begingroup\def\a{}\xparse#1.\relax.}
\def\xparse#1.#2.{%
  \ifx\relax#2%
    \edef\xparse\relax.{%
      \endgroup\ifx\a\empty\else[a=\a]\space\fi\ifx\\#1\\\else[b=#1]\fi
    }%
  \else
    \ifx\\#1\\\else
      \edef\a{\a\ifx\a\empty\else.\fi#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \xparse#2.%
}

\begin{document}
\parse{}

\parse{1}

\parse{1.2.3}

\parse{1..2..3}

\parse{4.5.6.7}

\parse{1.2}
\end{document}
```